# Loading ListView and ImageList while using a backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, listview, backgroundworker, imagelist

Loading the imagelist and the listview obviously causes the UI to hang a little.  So I'd like to load the UI and let the user know we are working on things and let the backgroundWorker do it's thing.  I tried on the formLoad to call the "backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();"

But I got "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

I poked around a bit and figured out that I need to change the code a bit.  So this is what I have:

```
    private void WatermarkPicker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


private void GetImages()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\pics");
        this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
        if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            listView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                () => this.listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1));
        }
        else
        {
            this.listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
        }
        int j = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                //this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                imageList1.Images.Add(file.Name, Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(file.Name);
                item.Tag = file.Name;
                item.ImageIndex = j;
                this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
                j++;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        GetCurrentLogos();
        GetImages();
    }
```

The if (listView1.InvokeRequired) is satisfied, and runs the listView1.invoke.  But nothing shows up in the listView in the UI.  No errors though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move all the code that tries to access the Listview AND the ImageList outside the DoWork event and use the ProgressChanged event raised inside the DoWork code.

In this way the code inside the ProgressChanged event is executed in the correct UI thread (assuming that the BackgroundWorker is created in the UI thread).

For example:

```
private void WatermarkPicker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
    listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;

    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not try to use in any way an object derived from Control
    // like the ListView when you are inside the DoWork method.....
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\pics");
    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        // You can't use imageList here
        // imageList1.Images.Add(file.Name, Image.FromFile(file.FullName));

        // Raise the ProgressChanged event. 
        // The code there will execute in the UI Thread
        worker.ReportProgress(1, file);        
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,  ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // This code executes in the UI thread, no problem to 
    // work with Controls like the ListView
    try
    {
        FileInfo file = e.UserState as FileInfo;
        imageList1.Images.Add(file.Name, Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(file.Name);
        item.Tag = file.Name;
        item.ImageIndex = imageList1.Images.Count - 1;
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        ....
     }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach of using ProgressChange to update the UI.  However, using Image.FromFile on the UI thread could slow things down for the end user.

Comment: I'm still getting "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." for the ImageList.Image.Add when it's in the DoWork...

Comment: Just checked with Visual Studio now. Effectively, with a large set of images I get the Cross Thread exception. So the only possible workaround is to move the ImageList.Add in the ProgressChanged event. This will resolve the problem but the ListView is not updated until you end the loop over the files list

Comment: Tried this with an image list around 325 for the user to select from. Still locking up the UI until it's fully loaded. Thoughts?

Comment: I suggest to post a new question. As  I have said in the last comment, with this approach you still need to wait the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute what you want in the background worker as you should do in the main thread.  But each time you want to access a UI component, you need to do it under the main thread (also called UI thread).  The syntax depends if you are working under WPF, Windows Phone, Xamarin, etc.

With WPF, you should have something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* Your code here */ }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You **must** access `ListView` and `ImageList` from the UI thread not the background worker thread.

I suggest you move the initialisation logic into `WatermarkPicker_Load` which runs in the UI thread and then change the `foreach` loop to use `Control.Invoke`.

```
foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
{
    var image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
    var item = new ListViewItem(file.Name)
    {
        Tag = file.Name;
    }
    listView1.Invoke(() => 
    {
        imageList1.Images.Add(file.Name, image);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    });
}
```